# What are the main differences between those linux distro vs general daily linux we use?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, distributions

In one hand i have general daily linux: `Fedora/CentOS/ArchLinux/Ubuntu`. 
On other hand i have following:

- eCos
- FreeRTOS
- BuildRoot
- RTEMS
- openembedded
- uCLinux

Did anyone used those uncommon linux distro's often, where do they best suite for (server or desktop use or for nonstop services)?

Are they completely different then our general linux?

Comment: ecos is not a linux distribution. it does not run the linux kernel

Comment: The [eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/) web page says that "eCos is not related to the Linux operating system", so comparing it with Linux distributions is like comparing Windows CE with Fedora.

Comment: Ditto for many of the others mentioned. OTOH, I use my Android phone frequently... and wouldn't compare it to my day-in day-out Fedoras --- just _too_ different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to make the (common) assumption that computers can either be a desktop or a server.

There are a lot of other devices that run Linux/Unix around you:

- cars/trains/planes/...
- Tivo
- phones, tablets and other gadgets.
- a [watch](http://www.research.ibm.com/WearableComputing/linuxwatch/linuxwatch.html)
- ...

The requirements for running Linux on these platforms are fundamentally different from what your PC may be used to. Therefore, different distros are leaders on these markets.

Fedora, Ubuntu, CentOS, ArchLinux are direct competitors in the sense that, while they do things slightly differently, they are still targeting your PC and/or your server. In a slightly technical term, they are targeting the x86 architecture. (I believe these distros won't even support any other CPU architecture).

The other distros have different targets altogether. I can separate the examples you give into 2 categories:

- [Real-Time OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system):

*From your list: RTEMS, FreeRTOS, eCos.*

A kind of operating system that treats the *time* variable a bit differently. It is my understanding they run in environments where delays and bottlenecks are not tolerated. A common example would be a breaking system in a car.

- [Embedded OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_operating_system)

*From your list: uClinux, Openembedded, Buildroot* (Note that the latter is not a real distribution, rather a building environment.)

These operating systems target a wide variety of platforms and architectures. They are popular among the electronics/microcontroller crowd, where traditionally resources are scarce, and cross-compilation is very common.

To make things simple, think of the examples you mention as highly specialized distributions that do very specific tasks. It goes to attest to the wide range of domains the Linux kernel can cover and what are the kinds of challenges the people in the kernel development team have to face.

Comment: Nitpicking: Fedora, Ubuntu, Centos and ArchLinux don't just support x86. They also support AMD64, aka EM64T, aka `x86_64` which is very much not the same as `x86`. ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I thought about mentioning it. But I was making a slightly different point. x84 and amd64, while different architectures, are *generally* used in the same machines: desktop PC and servers. So, *only in the context of my answer*, I felt they were similar. Maybe I should change that.

Comment: @rahmu: Nice answer. Does it mean Arduino or Crestron/Extron is in categories of your point 1. Another confusion starts now. What is Linux RT Kernel vs FreeRTOS or eCos then? (Can Linux RT kernel be not same as eCos or FreeRTOS?)

Comment: You seem to be making the (also common) assumption that every OS that isn't Windows is Linux. Why is that? As mentioned before *"eCos is not related to the Linux operating system"*. Why are you struggling with this?

Comment: @rahmu: to measure, linux kernel which has rt features is equal to eCos or FreeRTOS. Else why would Linux ever design, upgrade kernel with rt kernel?

Comment: There are many groups of people who believes on what they know better. To me i do not know eCos nor FreeRTOS, but i do know Linux and its kernel. In my experience correct me if i am wrong. Linux rt kernel is equal to eCos or FreeRTOS or Crestron/extron (microcontrollers).

Comment: No. Operating systems of such diversity cannot be "equals" of each other.  Even where intended for similar applications each will have its unique aspects.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: i think they are, and not equals in terms of outlook, but performence would be much higher level in `linux rt kernel`

Comment: 1) linux rt kernel get tested by hundreds or many end uers daily hourly secondly 2) eCos or FreeRTOS does not get tested in such a higher volume, so nobody sees where they are weak for or where the bugs are laying...

Comment: Another point as argument, is `NASA shuttle used Ada language`, which used i guess either using tiny unix or linux, but not FreeRTOS sort of distro, not sure but that will answer about  robust/capability/reliable/performance/etc etc. What does NASA used in space ship where they used ADA?

Comment: @YumYumYum `RT` doesn't mean it has to be fast but that something has to happen until a specific time, e.g. every 10ms. If you look closely at the projects you see that they are different and not equals. And regarding your NASA point, the programming language of your application(s) has nothing to do with the operating system. I just googled and found http://weblog.cenriqueortiz.com/computing/2007/08/18/on-self-modifying-code-and-the-space-shuttle-os/ it seems NASA is using it's own OS which makes much more sense than using linux. Please don't spread FUD and inform yourself.

Comment: Picking even more nits: Fedora (or close relatives) run on several less known architectures too. Debian is promiscuous, if you aren't careful it will take over anything with a CPU within reach. And so on.

Comment: @YumYumYum: That the space shuttle ran software written in Ada doesn't mean that its computers were able to run (even severely stripped down) versions of Linux. Look up the specs of the machines...