# Hurd vs Plan9 vs Linux vs eCos vs FreeRTOS what are the main differences specially with Hurd?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, architecture, real-time

Hurd is actually not Unix nor Linux. But more superior says. Where Plan9 and Linux are in the range of Unix/Linux. eCos and FreeRTOS is also completely not unix/linux.

What is the main differences between Hurd and FreeRTOS/eCos and General Unix/Linux?

Can i name FreeRTOS or eCos tree as Hurd family? As those OS are not considered to be Linux nor Unix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the main differences between those linux distro vs general daily linux we use?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/what-are-the-main-differences-between-those-linux-distro-vs-general-daily-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No neither eCos nor FreeRTOS are Hurd based. They are different operating systems.

eCos and FreeRTOOS are Realtime Operating systems and don't have to do anything with Hurd. Don't try to just arbitrary put different kind of Operating systems together.

Plan9 is also considered a successor of Unix and is as far as i know not considered as a Unix system but has some Posix support.

Comment: Can i summarize that superior OS is Hurd then? Or would i say Plan9 and other OS is marketing superior whereas Hurd was less interested and became unpopular?

Comment: @YumYumYum It depends on your criteria but no you can't just say that Hurd is superior, you'd would have to argue why Hurd is in your opinion superior or better suited for a specific task.